# How to start Virtual box machines automatically when booting? Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, vmware, autostart

I wasted one day trying to follow any guides that I could find in order to make my Virtual Box machine start after system reboot.

Is there any updated in-depth guide that works with Virtual Box and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ?

I tried moving also to Vmware , the same issue , it seems you have to be a master-guru-expert to do something like this .... I don`t know what to do anymore.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is the goal to start the VMs before a person logs into the desktop? Or is it sufficient to start the VMs after the login sequence completes?

Comment: Please what is host and what is guest?

Comment: Virtualbox and VMware (Workstation) in standard install need a user to run the virtual machine and a running graphical interface (X, Wayland) of the user. Virtualbox can be started "headless". For VMware there are special products running "headless". https://github.com/phpvirtualbox/phpvirtualbox